# Setting file permissions in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, find

This script is not working the way I thought it would .
I though it would find all the scripts that have every one rwx permissions changed to the permissions of xx5

```
#!/bin/bash
# the / makes find inclusive


for file in `find . -perm /007 `
do
permissions=`stat -c %a $file`
permissions=${permissions:0:2}5
echo $permissions $file
chmod $permissions $file
done



#find . -perm /007
```

My intentions are to at least secure some files

Comment: How is it not working the way you thought it would? Are you getting any errors? Try running it with `bash -x <yourscript>` to trace the execution.

Comment: You are sure that you want to change only `o=rwx` to `o=rx` and not simply take away the write access for `others` i.e. making `o=rw` `o=r`?

Comment: Sounds like you want `chown -R o-w .`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas The point is to limit your `chown` call to the necessary files. May be a huge waste of time otherwise.

Comment: Somw quick thoughts: Do your file paths have spaces? Do you have permission to chmod the files? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

```
chmod -R o-w .
```

Will remove write permissions to *others* for every file in a safe way. It will however update the ctime of every file including the ones for which *others* already didn't have write access.

With GNU `chmod`, you can make it show which files needed updated with the -c option:

```
$ chmod -cR o-w .
mode of `./a' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0775 (rwxrwxr-x)
```

If you only want to remove `w` from *others* where they have `rwx`, you can do:

```
find . ! -type l -perm -7 -exec chmod o-w {} +
```

(and add `-vv` with GNU or FreeBSD `chmod` to see the details). But (especially since you're dealing with world writeable files) beware there's a race condition there, where someone with bad intentions having write access to any of the directories under there could replace a file with a symlink to some other file in between the time `find` checks it and `chmod` is executed and have you remove the write permissions to that file instead and cause havoc (think of a symlink to `/tmp` for instance).

Since you're using GNU `stat` syntax, chances are your `find` is the GNU `find`. Note that GNU `find` could display file attributes long before GNU `stat` was introduced so you don't need both.

```
find . ! -type l -perm -7 -printf '%m %p\n' -exec chmod o-w {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

`/007` will show your only files that have no permissions for `owner` and `group`, and all permissiosn (rwx) for `other`.

You might have more luck with `/o=rwx`.  That will match only the `other` permissions for the file.

**EDIT FOR CORRECTNESS:**

Apparently, you'll need to use `-perm -o=rwx`, because the `/o` is an inclusive filter, and would match files where `other` has `x`,`w`,`xw`,`r`,`rx`,`rw`, or `rwx` permissions.  Changing the leading character of the filter from `/` to `-`, makes the filter exclusive, and would only match files with `rwx` in the `other` field.

Comment: can you explain /0=rwx

Comment: You are wrong about `/o=rwx`. That matches e.g. files with `o=r`, too. `-perm -o=rwx` is needed.

Comment: @JamesAndino the `/o=rwx` filter is a permissions filter that looks for `r`(read), `w`(write),`x`(execute) bits being set.  The `o` means to compare the filter to the `other` field.  You could also specify `u` for user, or `g` for group.  or combinations, like `-perm -u=rwx,o=rwx` to match on both the `user` and `group` permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a performance nightmare: You create two processes for every file! One completely uselessly because `find` already has this information and can easily print it. This is a better solution:

```
find . -perm -o=rwx -printf "%m %p_\0" 2>/dev/null | 
  while read -r -d '' perms path; do
    path="${path%_}"
    echo "${perms} '${path}'" >&2
    printf "%s\0" "$path"
  done | xargs -0 chmod o=rx
```

Comment: I just learned @ least 4 things, and 1 of them is I don`t kno what im doing

Comment: @JamesAndino Sorry, I didn't want to make it more complicated than necessary but then the edit by someone else about the \0 stuff appeared... My recommendation: Read all questions and answers about shell and shell tools for a week. You will feel different afterwards. :)

Comment: no, no!  It was a compliment @ you.Ty.

Comment: @JamesAndino If you don't get a good answer to that here then you should make that a separate question. I can offer this: http://www.shelldorado.com/

Comment: `-perm -o=rwx` is not the same as `-perm /007`. You can't pass NUL characters to commands even builtin in `bash`, so that's the same as `read -rd ''`. Note that `read` does one `read()` system call per character. Your code won't work for filenames that end in space, tab or newline characters. `-printf` is GNU specific. On symlinks, you'll end up changing the mode of the targets, so possibly make some files world readable when they were not meant to (think of a symlink to your `ssh` private key)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `-o=rwx` is indeed not the same as `/007`. I mentioned in a comment to Tim Kennedy that `-o=rwx` is needed. I was aware that this proposal was not safe against stupid file names but so wasn't the questioner's code. Improbable that this ever causes problems; the version without `-0` would have done well but somebody wanted that changed... BTW: `/007` is GNU, too. Symlink handling can be wrong in both directions. Concerning the access rights change: You probably have noticed that I asked the OP about this problem but haven't received an answer.

Comment: Symlinks will always have o=rwx, but chmod changes the permissions of the target of the symlink. So anything but using `find -L` or excluding symlinks would be wrong. About -o=rwx vs /007, sorry I hadn'd read the initial question and comments carefully enough.